# Query in abap using the selected field

Tags: sql, abap

Hi so there's this field that i have to select until nothing can be selected.

e.g.

```
field 1 | field 2
________|__________
aaa     |  bbb
bbb     |  fff
fff     |  ccc
ccc     |  kkk
```

i need to select the field2 using field1 and modify the internal table then find it to field 1 and then get the field 2 again modify the table, then find it to field 1, same routine goes until nothing can be selected.

This is my code.

```
     DATA : BEGIN OF IT OCCURS 0,
         PARTNER  TYPE BUT000-PARTNER,
         PARTNER1 TYPE BUT050-PARTNER1,
         2        TYPE BUT050-PARTNER1,
         3        TYPE BUT050-PARTNER1,
         4        TYPE BUT050-PARTNER1,
         5        TYPE BUT050-PARTNER1,
         6        TYPE BUT050-PARTNER1,
         7        TYPE BUT050-PARTNER1,
         8        TYPE BUT050-PARTNER1,
         9        TYPE BUT050-PARTNER1,
         10       TYPE BUT050-PARTNER1,
       END OF IT.

SELECT BUT000~PARTNER BUT050~PARTNER2
  FROM BUT000
  INNER JOIN BUT050 ON BUT000~PARTNER EQ BUT050~PARTNER1
  INTO TABLE IT.

FIELD-SYMBOLS <FS_WA> TYPE ANY.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <FS_WA1> TYPE ANY.

data num type i value 1.
data num2 type string.
data str type string.
data partner(255) type c.

LOOP AT IT.
  partner =  it-partner1.
 while partner <> space.

    num = num + 1.
    num2 = num.
    concatenate 'it-' num2 into str.
    condense str.
    assign str to <fs_wa>.

    select single but050~partner2 into
      <fs_wa> from but050  where partner1 eq partner.

     partner = <fs_wa>.
    modify it from <fs_wa>.

    if num = 10.
      clear num.
     stop.
    exit.
    endif.

 endwhile.

ENDLOOP.
```

i need my internal table to look like this.

```
field 1 | field 2 | field 3 | field 4 | field 5
________|_________|_________|_________|________
aaa     | bbb     | fff     | ccc     | kkkk
```

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there any possible way to dynamically append column/ field to internal table depending on how many data was found?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. If you give us a precise example for input and output, we can help you figure out how. The example above is incomplete - I don't get the exact idea what your output should look like.

Comment: Hello @Florian i have modified the above code.

Comment: You need to look at RTTS to dynamically create the data structures you are storing the data in, then you can add as many columns as you would like.

Comment: Could you ask a more precise question, because you explain the goal, but not what is your current result, what you tried, what is your exact issue? (stackoverflow is for asking/answering precise questions, not to provide full code to solve problems)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I already solved it. many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I have solved my issue, though it's not the  outcome that I was trying to achieve but, this is quite okay.

this is what solved my issue.

```
    LOOP AT IT.

  INDEX = 2.
  DATA(PART) = IT-PARTNER1.
  DO .
    INDEX = INDEX + 1.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT INDEX OF STRUCTURE IT TO <FS>.

    IF SY-SUBRC <> 0.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.

    SELECT BUT050~PARTNER2 FROM BUT050
      WHERE PARTNER1 EQ  @PART
      AND  RELTYP IN ('ZBP002',
                      'ZBP003',
                      'ZBP004',
                      'ZBP005',
                      'ZBP006',
                      'ZBP007',
                      'ZBP008',
                      'ZBP009',
                      'ZBP010',
                      'ZBP011')
      ORDER BY RELTYP ASCENDING
      INTO @<FS>.
    ENDSELECT.

    IF IT-PARTNER NE <FS>  AND IT-PARTNER1 NE <FS>.
      PART = <FS>.
      MODIFY IT.
    ELSE.
      PART = ''.
    ENDIF.
  ENDDO.

ENDLOOP.
```

Many thanks! best regards :)